# Changing the progress bar colour manually

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, progress-bar

(I dont want to change the background colour)

How do you change the colour of the progressbar in xml and kotlin manually. The effect I want is so when the progress bar is 1/5 it is red, 3/5 turns it yellow. 5/5 turns it green.

I have all the other functionality just the color seems impossible to change this way? The section of code where I am changing the progress bar is in this when statement.

```
when(count){
            0 -> {
                passwordProgressBar.progress = 0
                "change colour here"??
            }
            1 -> {
                passwordProgressBar.progress = 2
            }
            2 -> {
                passwordProgressBar.progress = 4
            }
            3 -> {
                passwordProgressBar.progress = 6
            }
            4 -> {
                passwordProgressBar.progress = 8
            }
            5 -> {
                passwordProgressBar.progress = 10
            }
        }
```

Solution Edit *

The .setColorFilter() method was deprecated but still functioned. Used a white background and set filter dynamically to whatever I wanted it in the when statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Try this..

 progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
            Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```